# How to determine if a record is just created or updated in after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

The #new_record? function determines if a record has been saved. But it is always false in the `after_save` hook. Is there a way to determine whether the record is a newly created record or an old one from update?

I'm hoping not to use another callback such as `before_create` to set a flag in the model or require another query into the db.

Any advice is appreciated.

Edit: Need to determine it in `after_save` hook, and for my particular use case, there is no `updated_at` or `updated_on` timestamp

Comment: hmm maybe pass a param in a before_save? just thinking out loud

Comment: [persisted?](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F)

Answer (score 197, accepted):

I was looking to use this for an `after_save` callback.

A simpler solution is to use `id_changed?` (since it won't change on `update`) or even `created_at_changed?` if timestamp columns are present.

Update: As @mitsy points out, if this check is needed outside of callbacks then use `id_previously_changed?`. See [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes).

Comment: via [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Comment: It's best to differentiate with an after_update and an after_create. The callbacks can share a common method that takes an argument to indicate if it's a create or update.

Comment: This might has changed. At least in Rails 4, the after_save callback runs after the after_create or after_update callback (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).

Comment: Checking neither of these fields work outside of `after_save`.

Comment: That's a smart way to check.

Comment: I think use `after_create` and `before_create` is a good solution.

Comment: `id_changed?` will be false after the record is saved (outside of the hooks at least).  In that case, you can use `id_previously_changed?`

Comment: It looks like `id_changed?` is being deprecated in favor of `saved_change_to_id?`. I saw this message in the console after using `id_changed?`:

"DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `attribute_changed?` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_change_to_attribute?` instead."

Comment: `id_previously_changed` (or `saved_change_to_id`) won't work (at least on Rails 5.2.0) if your record was just created with nested attributes for another record. Instead, you can use `transaction_include_any_action?([:create])`, which is unaffected.

Comment: @matthuhiggins what argument are you talking about? AR doesn't pass any arguments to the `do_something` callback declared as `after_create :do_something` or `after_update :do_something`

Comment: I like to be specific even I aware that `:id` shouldn't change in normal, but
`id_change.first.nil?`

Answer (score 33):

No rails magic here that I know of, you'll have to do it yourself. You could clean this up using a virtual attribute...

In your model class:

```
def before_save
  @was_a_new_record = new_record?
  return true
end

def after_save
  if @was_a_new_record
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 30):

Yet another option, for those who *do* have an `updated_at` timestamp:

```
if created_at == updated_at
  # it's a newly created record
end
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it seems that this could backfire in some situations (not necessarily bullet proof).

Comment: Depending upon when a migration is run the created_at and updated_at records could be off. Also you always run the chance of somebody updating a record right after initially saving it which could put the time just out of sync. Its not a bad idea, just feels like a more bullet proof implementation could be added.

Comment: Also they might be equal long after the record was initially created. If a record isn't updated for months, it's going to look like it was _just created_.

Comment: @bschaeffer Great thinking. Within the scope of the question though (an `after_save` callback), is that possible?

Comment: @bschaeffer Sorry, my question was "is it possible for `created_at` to equal `updated_at` in an `after_save` callback at any time other than when it is first created?"

Comment: @colllin: When creating a record, `created_at` and `updated_at` will be equal in an `after_save` callback. In all other situations, they will not be equal in the `after_save` callback.

Answer (score 23):

There is an `after_create` callback which is only called if the record is a new record, *after it is saved*.  There is also an `after_update` callback for use if this was an existing record which was changed and saved. The `after_save` callback is called in both cases, after either `after_create` or `after_update` is called.

Use `after_create` if you need something to happen once after a new record has been saved.

More info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: This might not be true actually. If you have associations in your creation, then after_create is called BEFORE the associations are created, so if you need to make sure EVERYTHING is created, then you need to use after_save

Comment: Thumbs down to this answer as this is totally wrong. In most cases `after_create` hasn't stored the record in the database when called.

Answer (score 19):

Since the object has already been saved, you would you need to look at the previous changes.  The ID should only change after a create.

```
# true if this is a new record
@object.previous_changes[:id].any?
```

There is also an instance variable `@new_record_before_save`.  You can access that by doing the following:

```
# true if this is a new record
@object.instance_variable_get(:@new_record_before_save)
```

Both are pretty ugly, but they would allow you to know whether the object has been newly created.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm currently in byebug in an `after_save` callback using Rails 4 and neither of these are working to identify this new record.

Comment: I'd say that `@object.previous_changes[:id].any?` is quite simple and elegant. It works for me after the record gets updated (I do not call it from `after_save`).

Comment: `@object.id_previously_changed?` is a bit less ugly.

Comment: @MCB in `after_save` on Rails 4 you'd want to look at `changes[:id]` instead of `previous_changes[:id]`. This is changing in Rails5.1 however (see discussion in https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25337)

Comment: `previous_changes.key?(:id)` for a better understanding.

Answer (score 15):

There is a method called `previously_new_record?` for exactly this use case.

```rb
user = User.new

user.new_record? # => true
user.previously_new_record? # => false

user.save

user.new_record? # => false
user.previously_new_record? # => true
```

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-previously_new_record-3F

Looks like the proposed workaround by calling `saved_change_to_id?` doesn't work anymore. I'm on Rails 7.

Answer (score 14):

Rails 5.1+ way:

```
user = User.new
user.save!
user.saved_change_to_attribute?(:id) # => true
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4 (checked on 4.2.11.1) results of `changes` and `previous_changes` methods are empty hashes `{}` on object creation inside `after_save`. So `attribute_changed?` methods like `id_changed?` won't work as expected.

But you can take advantage of this knowledge and - knowing that at least 1 attribute has to be in `changes` on update - check if `changes` is empty. Once you confirm that it's empty, you must be during object creation:

```
after_save do
  if changes.empty?
    # code appropriate for object creation goes here ...
  end
end
```