# Error saving record when custom validation is in place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attr-accessor

I have this API that saves videos, indexes them and updates them. In order to reduce the times the indexing was happening I decided to add some validation to only index videos that had changed or that where new. Before it was like so:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save :index_me

  def index_me
    Resque.enqueue(IndexVideo, self.id)
  end

end
```

The changes I made are as follows:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :check_new_record
  after_save :index_me

  def check_new_record
    self.is_new = self.new_record?
  end

  def index_me
    if self.changed? || self.is_new
      Resque.enqueue(IndexVideo, self.id)
    end
  end

end
```

Without the changes everything's fine with the exception that every video gets indexed even if nothing changed. But with my changes, when a video tries to save to the database it rolls back. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you create a new Video at the console, save it, and show us the log output (including the SQL in the log).

Comment: Can we see the IndexVideo class?

Comment: IndexVideo makes an HTTP post to the indexing server, no interaction with the database, so I don't think it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If I'm not wrong, when a `before` callback returns `false`, the transaction gets rolled back.**
That's probably what's happening.

```
def check_new_record
    self.is_new = self.new_record?
end
```

When `self.new_record?` returns `false`, it assigns `false` to `self.is_new` and then the method returns `self.is_new`, which is `false` too.

Try this instead:

```
def check_new_record
    self.is_new = self.new_record?
    true
end
```

Comment: Looks like the case. [Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#halting-execution)

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you can get rid of the hack you have to detect if the record is new in the after_save.  If the record is new, the .changed? method will return true.

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :index_me

  def index_me
    Resque.enqueue(IndexVideo, self.id) if self.changed?
  end
end
```

Comment: I tested and after saving the record .changed? is false

Comment: Check out this previously answered question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975106/how-to-determine-if-a-record-is-just-created-or-updated-in-after-save