# How to check if a model instance was updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, conditional-statements

I've searched through the site on how to accomplish this and many answers point towards using the `changed?` method. I'm trying to notify users of an update **after persisting the DB** so unfortunately this won't work.

I then found the `previous_changes` method but this also triggers when a post is first created. The goal for is to do this only edit actions. How can this be done?

```
<% if @post.previous_changes %>
  <span>Updated:</span> <span><%= time_ago_in_words(@post.updated_at) %> ago</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you looked into the gem paper_trail? Maybe your question is not as clear as it could be?

Comment: I think this would work? `<% if @post.created_at != @post.updated_at %>`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to set a flag whenever the element is updated.

```
class Model
  after_update :flag_update    

  def updated?
    !!@updated
  end

  private

  def flag_update
    @updated = true
  end
end
```

Then in your code simply check `@post.updated?`.

Comment: Why the double `!!`s?

Comment: @CarlEdwards, when `@updated` is not defined, it returns `nil`. If you do `!!` it will return `false` for `nil`.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. What's the main difference between a single `!` and a double `!!`. I thought one was enough to negate something.

Comment: @CarlEdwards It is; this coerces to an actual boolean value instead of relying on truthy/falsey.

Comment: Strangely couldn't get this to work. Just to give you an idea, both methods are setup in the `Post` model. I created a new post and the `Updated At` field doesn't show up (as expected). When I do update that post nothing shows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have an updated record when

```
@post.previous_changes.present? && @post.previous_changes["id"].nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good candidate for using `after_update` [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#updating-an-object) and in it calling a job to send an e-mail, text message or whatever your means of notifying a user is.

Using the callback to flag the model instance basically adds a state for the model and only works once because it is set after the first update. Any subsequent updates might go unnoticed depending on what and how you want to notify your users, unless you could somehow reset the state (flag), which may be a lot more work than what it is worth.

Relying on the `updated_at` timestamp to be greater than the `created_at` suffers from the same one-time opportunity than flagging.

We used an approach where we checked what a model's `changes` returns (you could also use `changed?`) before saving it, and then sent a notification after a successful save.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to call `previous_changes`, why not just add a conditional to make sure that `id` was not changed (as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7183918/1143732)):

```
<% if @post.previous_changes && !@post.id_changed? %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Similar to Wizard of Ogz's answer this doesn't work either.